# How to apply the highest discount rule under Magento

Tags: magento, rules, promotions

How can I apply only the highest discount rule under customer cart?
Imagine 2 rules, one with 10% and another one with 15%.
When the customer goes to the cart, he needs to receive 15% of discount.

Is it possible?

Please note that I would not like to consider the rule priority. I would like to guarantee that the customer will always receive the best promotion.

Comment: why would you not consider priority?  That allows you to list the 15% off first, then the 10% off second.  So if they qualify for both, they get the 15% and then stop rules processing.  I think listing them in priority order from best discount to worst is very logical and would solve this.

Comment: I have the same understanding, thank you for your analisys. My issue is regarding with multiple matching rules, and I would like to evaluate and apply the highest rule. Imagine that we have two promotion with the same priority, and eligible to be applied. How to extend magento in order to aplly the best rule for the customer, in other words, with the highest discount? It is a good challenge :)

Comment: I guess in your example it was obvious.  Put the "15% Off" before the "10% Off" and you'll always be right.  But I can see this being an issue if it's storewide 10% off vs.  15% items in one category....because depending on the products in the cart one promotion could be "better", and with a different product selection the other promo is better.  There are several promotion extensions available, I feel like this problem can be simply stated but making it happen is very complex, mainly because magento's promotions aren't set up for it.  I'll tackle it in the future, good luck with it for now.

Comment: @cocardoso got any solution for this?